# Absolute Positioning TR & TD Elements

Tags: css, positioning, css-position, html-table, tablerow

i am trying to absolute position a ASP.NET Datalist which inside a table with TR & TD elements - i have the TR displaying horizontally - applying the absolute positioning just shows the last TD element. Using relative/static shows the entire TD elements which is how it should be - i need to have it absolutely positioned in one position - finding it hard to get it right - any suggestions?

```
.AspNet-DataList table 
{ 
width: 200px;
}

.AspNet-DataList tr, .AspNet-DataList td 
{
float: left;
left: 250px;
padding-right: 2px;
position: absolute;
top: 304px;
}

.AspNet-DataList td a
{
text-indent: -9999em;
display:block;
height: 25px;
width: 25px;
}
```

It is a step by step form which has a cirlce orange background with number 1 to 6 which is being displayed horizontally - thought id mention it just in case your thinking what im trying to achieve. I hate to use position:absolute but sometimes it just something you require at the time and cant do without it.

Here is the form and the divs;

```
<div class="radarform">
<div class="look-for">Look For</div>
<div class="agree">Agree</div>
<div class="strongly-agree">Strongly Agree</div>
<div class="disagree">Disagree</div>
<div class="strongly-disagree">Strongly Disagree</div>
<energy:FormBuilder ID="HealthAndSafetyRadarForm" runat="server" XmlPath="~/asset/forms/securusradarform.xml" CssClass="hsRadarform" ButtonText="Send Form" ShowTitle="true" ShowSideBar="true" />
<div class="clear-me"></div>
</div>
```

In Firefox FireBug it shows this and has its own class that i am using;

```
<div id="ctl07_HealthAndSafetyRadarForm_Wizard_SideBarContainer_SideBarList" class="AspNet-DataList">
```

#### **UPDATE:** I managed to sort the problem out - i was positioning the td so they were ending up beind each other - i did this on the table and then positioned the hsRadarForm relatively - that has sorted it out - gosh i hate position:absolute.

```
.AspNet-DataList table 
{
left: 45px;
position: absolute;
top: -46px;
width: 175px;
}

.AspNet-DataList tr, .AspNet-DataList td 
{
float: left;
padding-right: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap the data list in a DIV and absolutely position that? It's sometimes easier to put things in a container and absolutely position those.

Comment: it is wrapped inside a `<div class="radarform"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to achieve - something about a circular orange background? - but if you really do need to reposition td elements, you will almost certainly  need to set the td, tr, tbody, and table to `display: block;`

Comment: have a look at the link - that is what i have so far and im trying to position this absolute but for some reason its showing the number 6 only - do i need to display block? i used block and text indent to hide the text and i used jQuery to add the background circles [CLICK HERE TO VIEW](http://snpr.cm/wnlm1x.png)